# Simple check in java to find out if running as administrator

Tags: windows, administrator

Is there a simple, quick, non-invasive windows admin task that can be performed from a java process to validate if the current process is running as administrator?

I know we could run batch commands to check if current user is member of administrator group. But there are complications of portability across Vista etc.

A simple example would be:

```
echo. 2> %SYSTEMROOT%\EmptyFile.txt
```

However, this is invasive. We dont want to create files

Any other option?

Comment: f the file system is FAT instead of NTFS, the test you propose would not work.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you may find it a better choice to check for a specific permission rather than implying permissions from role assignments.  One reason for this is that in a domain environment you may have local administrators *and* domain administrators.  They are not necessarily equivalent.  Also, even an administrator's permissions can be altered or specific file/directory permissions be "tweaked" to, for example, deny access to "localmachine\administrators".

Checking for a specific permission guarantees that, given specific user credentials, that user can or cannot perform some action, regardless of what roles they might be assigned to.

I know that doesn't answer your question, but it may help shed some light on the problem of assuming permissions from roles.