# How to determine if java program is running as administrator at run time

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, admin, administration

I have a java program, which will run on windows, which I want to run differently, based on if the program is run with administrative privileges, versus if the program is run as a normal user.

I need a solution that is general, which can work for different flavors of java (not just oracle/sun's version).

Comment: See this post and it's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834490/simple-check-in-java-to-find-out-if-running-as-administrator

Comment: I've been looking into this issue for a while, and seem some different approaches. I noticed that I can try to run 'reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19"' from a normal console and will get an error, where when run as administrator, it returns values. I may end up going with this approach unless someone else has a clearer way to detecting access level.

Comment: @NiekTax thanks for the link. That is one of the background links I looked at before posting the question. My particular situation is based around if I'll be able to write to HKLM, either a domain or local admin should be able to do that. I have a solution working using the regkey stuff in my previous comment. I'll post it a while later if no comes up with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the reg query approach to determine if the current program is admin access or not. The following should give enough info that you can modify it for your needs.

```
    try {
        String command = "reg query \"HKU\\S-1-5-19\"";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();                            // Wait for for command to finish
        int exitValue = p.exitValue();          // If exit value 0, then admin user.

        if (0 == exitValue) {
            System.out.println("admin user");
        } else {
            System.out.println("non admin user");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This solution will fail for a member of the `Domain Admins` group `S-1-5-21domain-512`.